# Colocar el cursor en un input dentro de un modal al mostrarlo

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo este código HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton1" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'>
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="texto" value="1">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Y éste es el código JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#boton1').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#texto').focus();
        });
        
    });
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando le doy clic al modal no se ubica el cursor en el `<input>` y la verdad no sé qué esté haciendo mal.

Si lo utilizo fuera del modal sí funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes darle el foco a un elemento que aún no ha sido mostrado. Al recibir el evento `click` en el botón aún no está en pantalla la ventana modal.

Para eso existe [un evento llamado `shown.bs.modal`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) que se dispara en el momento en el que se ha mostrado la ventana modal, por lo que puedes usarlo para forzar el foco:

> **Event Type:** shown.bs.modal
>
> **Description:** This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

En castellano:

> **Tipo de Evento:** shown.bs.modal
>
> **Descripción:** Este evento se dispara cuando la ventana modal se ha hecho visible al usuario (esperará a que se completen las transiciones CSS). Si está causado por un clic, el objeto pulsado estará disponible como propiedad  `relatedTarget` del evento.

Podrías usarlo de esta manera:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#texto').focus();
})
```

Aquí lo tienes en funcionamiento:

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#texto').focus();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton1" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal'>
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="texto" value="1">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me sirvio mucho y tiene mucha logica lo que dices. no lo habia tomado en cuenta

Comment: ¡Un placer ser de ayuda!